# How to dismiss first popover and show second popver in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 screen. on first screen i have one button on click of that i am showing one popover. In that popover i have one button and on that button click i want to open another popover but first popover should get dismiss?

is there any way to achieve this?

I am using this kind of way to show popover viewcontroller

```
@IBAction func btnManualEntry(_ sender: Any) {

        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SummaryManualEditVC") {
            vc.modalTransitionStyle   = .crossDissolve;
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: no need to dismiss first .. you can show popover over it

Comment: Thanks but after dismissing second i dont want to show first popover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reference the `presentingViewController`, and when you dismiss the first popover, open the other after it has been dismissed.

```
@IBAction func btnManualEntry(_ sender: Any) {

    if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SummaryManualEditVC") {
                vc.modalTransitionStyle   = .crossDissolve;
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                presentingVC.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
}
```